# How to name unnamed fields in a C structure?

Tags: c, structure, naming-conventions

Let's consider this structure:

```
struct {
    int a;
    int _reserved_000_[2];
    int b;
    int _reserved_001_[12];
    int c;    
};
```

The reserved fields should never be read or written. My structure represents a descriptor to address an FPGA where I got a lot of `reserved` fields. I eventually named them with random named because after years the initial ascending numbering doesn't mean anything anymore.

So I have now:

```
struct {
    int a;
    int _reserved_3hjdds1_[2];
    int b;
    int _reserved_40iuljk_[12];
    int c;    
};
```

It would be more convenient to have just empty fields instead:

```
struct {
    int a;
    int;
    int b;
    int;
    int c;    
};
```

But it doesn't work.

What other alternative can I just that avoid finding unique name for `reserved` fields?

Comment: Write a code generator with which to produce the struct declarations.  Let it create sequentially numbered names for the reserved members.  Note in particular that it does not matter if the names of the reserved members change, because no one is supposed to be accessing those members.

Comment: Do you mean something like `reserved_## __COUNTER__`

Comment: Since nobody is supposed to use the reserved fields, I don't see how it matters whether the initial ascending numbering is meaningful -- it's only used to make the names unique anyway.  I'd have stuck with the first version...

Comment: @Dmitri I totally agree with you, but readability is better when you don't have these garbage names all the way around.

Comment: @nowox, not really.  The preprocessor cannot count.  I mean write a separate program, in the language of your choice, to generate a header containing your struct declarations based on some simple to write and ingest representation of the needed contents.  Maintain the data among your source files, and regenerate the header when the data change.

Comment: Note also that you could just do the equivalent manually.  Since, again, the names of the reserved fields don't matter as long as they are distinct within each structure type, you could return to numbered fields and just perform manual renumbering as needed.

Comment: I could see an corner issue with `__COUNTER__`.  If the `struct` definition was in an `*.h` header and various `*.c` files included it , might not the  `__COUNTER__` state may differ depending on how `__COUNTER__` was used prior to the `*.h` inclusion?  Would `struct` with different field names via separate compilation work or create debugging issues?  IDK.  IAC, a good post.

Comment: For what its worth, I regularly see `padding` and `unused` (suffixed by a decimal number if more than one occurs in the same structure) used for this. (`reserved` is rare, `internal` even rarer.) My suggestion: Do not try to hold idiot developers' hands. If they want, let them shoot themselves in the foot. Just try to make the sane stuff easier than the insane/idiotic, and clearly mark the expectations the code has, as well as current future plans, so that no unwarranted assumptions are made (by anyone rational).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to achieve what you want with a bit of macro-magic:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
#define EXPAND(x, y) CONCAT(x, y)
#define RESERVED EXPAND(reserved, __LINE__)

struct
{
  uint32_t x;
  uint32_t RESERVED;
  uint16_t y;
  uint64_t RESERVED[10];
} s;
```

This gives you identifiers such as `reserved11`, `reserved13`, but the names obviously don't matter.

Comment: Nice try, but I still prefer my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42838409/2612235=) with the CAPITAL macros and the warning about `__COUNTER__`. You also forgot to `#include <stdint.h>`.

Comment: @nowox `__LINE__` is standard C, `__COUNTER__` is not.

Comment: Notice that `__LINE__` will not work if you have multiple definition on the same line, but at least you will get an error from the compiler. I still think this is better than `__COUNTER__`

Comment: @nowox And that's a nice feature, yes? Why would you declare several struct members on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

I know, this answer comes way too late but how about using unnamed bitfields?

```
struct {
    int a;
    int : sizeof(int) * 8;
    int b;
    int : sizeof(int) * 8;
    int c;
};
```

This is ISO-C89 standard and works with every C and C++ compiler I've met so far, including: gcc, g++, clang, Borland C++, even with old TurboC.

Comment: OK for 1 `int`, yet OP needs 2 and 12 `int`.  `int : sizeof(int) * 8 * 2` and `int : sizeof(int) * 8 * 12;` lead to " error: width of '<anonymous>' exceeds its type".

Comment: You get this Error, because you are defining a Bitfield of integer type. Depending on your machine and system it usually is 32Bits. So your Integer Bitfield has a maximum size of `int` which I guess is 32 Bits. So `sizeof(int) * 8 * 2` will give you a result of 64. This is double the size that is possible for the type you've defined.
If you need more than 1 `int` just add as many lines with `int : sizeof(int) * 8;` as you need.

Comment: Cluttering up the source with 12 lines instead of `int _reserved_001_[12];` would be much worse for readability and maintainability.  Worse, this is visually noisier than the regular variable names, distracting the eye from them.  It's an interesting idea, but not very good for the specific use-case the question is proposing.  Perhaps could be useful for other future readers, especially if they don't need fields wider than one `long long` or `uintmax_t`

Comment: This technic is called structure padding. But you're totally right. It isn't just ugly to look at and painfull to maintain, furthermore it even is tricky to read or write to those fields. This is far far away from clean code. C just doesn't provide private or hidden fields and every attempt to achive something like this is an indicator for a bad program architecture. But as you said, it is an interesting idea to play around with.